# LonLat values returning from Openlayers 2

Tags: google-maps, openlayers-2, latitude-longitude, maps

I have developed an app using Openlayers 2 to retrieve the latitude and longitude values based on the clicked position.

The map display the area of Great Britain and Northern Ireland.

Below the code I wrote for that.

```
var lonlat = self._map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(evt.xy);
```

However Lonlat value it return is 
      ***Latitude : 515881.5 and Longitude : 172199***

I'm not sure whether these values are correct or not. Because Google map gives a different LonLat values for same area. [[link]](http://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html)

The values from google maps are Latitude : 51.438677  Longitude : -0.335115

I want to know how to retrieve the LatLon from openlayers 2 if this is wrong.

**Edit : This is the object returning from Openlayers end**

```
initialize
lat
:
256465
lon
:
385906.5
__proto__
:
Object
CLASS_NAME
:
"OpenLayers.LonLat"
add
:
(lon, lat)
arguments
:
null
caller
:
null
length
:
2
name
:
"add"
prototype
:
Object
constructor
:
(lon, lat)
arguments
:
null
caller
:
null
length
:
2
name
:
"add"
prototype
:
Object
__proto__
:
()
[[FunctionLocation]]
:
OpenLayers.debug.js:1867
[[Scopes]]
:
Scopes[1]
0
:
Global
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
()
[[FunctionLocation]]
:
OpenLayers.debug.js:1867
[[Scopes]]
:
Scopes[1]
clone
:
()
arguments
:
null
caller
:
null
length
:
0
name
:
"clone"
prototype
:
Object
__proto__
:
()
[[FunctionLocation]]
:
OpenLayers.debug.js:1852
[[Scopes]]
:
Scopes[1]
equals
:
(ll)
arguments
:
null
caller
:
null
length
:
1
name
:
"equals"
prototype
:
Object
__proto__
:
()
[[FunctionLocation]]
:
OpenLayers.debug.js:1887
[[Scopes]]
:
Scopes[1]
initialize
:
(lon, lat)
arguments
:
null
caller
:
null
fromArray
:
(arr)
fromString
:
(str)
length
:
2
name
:
"initialize"
prototype
:
Object
__proto__
:
()
[[FunctionLocation]]
:
OpenLayers.debug.js:1813
[[Scopes]]
:
Scopes[1]
lat
:
0
lon
:
0
toShortString
:
()
arguments
:
null
caller
:
null
length
:
0
name
:
"toShortString"
prototype
:
Object
__proto__
:
()
[[FunctionLocation]]
:
OpenLayers.debug.js:1841
[[Scopes]]
:
Scopes[1]
toString
:
()
arguments
:
null
caller
:
null
length
:
0
name
:
"toString"
prototype
:
Object
__proto__
:
()
[[FunctionLocation]]
:
OpenLayers.debug.js:1830
[[Scopes]]
:
Scopes[1]
transform
:
(source, dest)
arguments
:
null
caller
:
null
length
:
2
name
:
"transform"
prototype
:
Object
__proto__
:
()
[[FunctionLocation]]
:
OpenLayers.debug.js:1908
[[Scopes]]
:
Scopes[1]
0
:
Global
wrapDateLine
:
(maxExtent)
arguments
:
null
caller
:
null
length
:
1
name
:
"wrapDateLine"
prototype
:
Object
__proto__
:
()
[[FunctionLocation]]
:
OpenLayers.debug.js:1927
[[Scopes]]
:
Scopes[1]
__proto__
:
Object
```

**Edit 2: These are my grid references**
"gridReference": "386170,256495",

**Edit 3**

```
projection: "EPSG:27700",
        units: "m",
        maxExtent: {
            left: -521611.7877215,
            bottom: -99060.2018315805,
            right: 1107515.6274664556,
            top: 1234593.14792
        },

        scales: [1.025694, 0.533333, 0.238194, 0.139583, 0.090278, 1.35, 1.17, 1.08, 1.04, 1.02],
        resolutions: [1,0.5,0.25,0.1,0.05,0.025,0.0125,0.00625,0.003125,0.0015625,0.00078125],

        controls: ["navigation", "panZoomBar", "scaleLine", "mousePosition", "attribution", "loadingPanel", "navigationHistory"],
        controlPanel: {
            controls: ["zoomBox", "measure", "getFeature"],
            defaultControl: "panPanel"
        }
```

Comment: It seems you get projected coordinates instead of geographic long&lat. Check if you define some projected reference system anywhere in your application.

Comment: @NadyaB. How can I check the reference system?

Comment: Please do not *ever* state you have a "urgent requirement" in in a volunteer environment like GIS SE. All it does is generate downvotes and encourages folks to *ignore* your question.

Comment: Show the code....

Comment: @NadyaB. Please see the edit 2

Comment: @BradHards The  code line to retrieve LongLat from openlayers is in the question. And see the edits as well.

Comment: I'm more interested with how you set up the map. Somewhere you probably have EPSG:27700.

Comment: @BradHards See the edit 3. Can't show the whole codebase which is quite large.

Answer (score 1):

As Nadya B. pointed out, your coordinates are projected (in OSGB36, which is what the `projection: "EPSG:27700"` part means).

If you want your map to be in lon/lat, use `EPSG:4326` or similar.

If you want to keep your projected coordinates map, and just get the results in a longitude / latitude, use proj4js or similar to convert the results. Examples are provided in the openlayers doc: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/using-proj4js.html and http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/graticule.html